# How to call parameterized stored procedure in jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I need to call a parameterized stored procedure in java jdbc from sql server.
The stored procedure goes like this in sql

```
create proc patientreg
@id int
    as
begin
    select [patient_id],[Psurname], [pFirstname], [pMiddlename], [reg_date], [DOB], [Sex], [Phone_num], [Addr],[Email],[dbo].[fncomputeage](DOB) from [dbo].[Patient_registration] where [patient_id] = @id
end
```

please note `dbo.fncompute(DOB)` is a function

To call it in JDBC:

```
try{
    String str = "{call patientreg(?)}";
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbcdbc:GeneralHospital");
    cstmt = con.prepareCall(str);
    cstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(t.getText()));
    cstmt.execute();

    int pid = cstmt.getInt(1);
    String sname = cstmt.getString(2);
    String fname = cstmt.getString(3);
    String mname = cstmt.getString(4);
    String regdate = cstmt.getString(5);
    String dob = cstmt.getString(6);
    String sex = cstmt.getString(7);
    String phonenum = cstmt.getString(8);
    String address = cstmt.getString(9);
    String email = cstmt.getString(10);
    int age = cstmt.getInt(11);

    l1.setText(sname+""+ fname+""+mname);
    l3.setText(Integer.toString(pid));
    l4.setText(regdate);
    l5.setText(dob);
    l6.setText(Integer.toString(age));
    l7.setText(sex);
    l8.setText(phonenum);
    l9.setText(address);
    l10.setText(email);
    cstmt.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("Error occured");
    System.out.println("Error:"+ex);
}
```

After doing it this way it throwing an exception:

> Error:java.sql.SQLException: Parameter 1 is not an OUTPUT parameter

Comment: Just a remark: beware that since java release 8 and onwards, the JDBC-ODBC bridge has been removed from the JDK, so you would need to look for some pure java alternative driver

Answer (score 1):

there is a couple of problems with your code.

First, Don't use the jdbc odbc driver! It is unstable, and might not work correctly. Use Microsoft's [own jdbc driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx), or, even better, use [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/), which is an excellent open source jdbc driver for Sql Server.

Second, the `getInt`, `getString` etc methods on [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) is used to retrieve output parameters from the stored procedure. What you have is an ordinary resultset.

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call patientreg(?)}");

// add input parameter
cstmt.setInt(1, someInteger);

// execute and get resultset.
ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();

// read resultset
while (rs.next()) {
    int pid = rs.getInt(1);
    String sname = rs.getString(2);
    String fname = rs.getString(3);
    // etc.
}

// remember to close statement and connection
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement cs=null;
Connection conn=getJNDIConnection();
try {
cs=conn.prepareStatement("exec sp_name ?,?");
cs.setString(1, "val1");
cs.setString(2, "val2");
rs = cs.executeQuery();
ArrayList<YourClass> listYourClass = new ArrayList<YourClass>();
while (rs.next()) {
    YourClassret= new YourClass();
    ret.set1(rs.getString(1));
    ret.set2(rs.getString(2));
    ret.set3(rs.getString(3));
    listaObjectX.add(ret);

}
return listYourClass ;
 } catch (SQLException se) {
    System.out.println("Error "+ se.getMessage());
    se.printStackTrace();

} finally {

    try {

        rs.close();
        cs.close();
      con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //do ex.print
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have never called an SQL-server stored procedure, but is not this supposed to be done with CallableStatement?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use CallableStatement when calling stored procedures. The above will only work, as long as you don't need to retrieve the return value or any output parameters of the stored procedure.